# System of vectors equations in the plane

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, polar-coordinates

I have a practical problem (let's call it problem $P_1$) like the following:

there are three vectors $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(x_1,x_2) = (r_x\cos{\theta_x}, r_x\sin{\theta_x})$, $(y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(y_1,y_2) = (r_y\cos{\theta_y}, r_y\sin{\theta_y})$ and $(z_1, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

$$(y_1, y_2) = (x_1,x_2) + (z_1,0)$$

$r_x$ and $r_y$ are known. I know also $\alpha_x = \theta_x + \beta$ and $\alpha_y = \theta_y + \beta$. **Values of $\beta$ and $z_1$ are unknown** and must be determined.

I have a solution for this problem:

$$z_1 = \sqrt{r_x^2+r_y^2-2r_xr_y\cos{(\alpha_x-\alpha_y)}}$$

$$\beta = \alpha_x - atan2\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha_x-\alpha_y)}{\cos(\alpha_x-\alpha_y)-\frac{r_x}{r_y}}\right)$$

Now suppose that I have a similar problem $P_2$:

there are five vectors $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(x_1,x_2) = (r_x\cos{\theta_x}, r_x\sin{\theta_x})$, $(y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(y_1,y_2) = (r_y\cos{\theta_y}, r_y\sin{\theta_y})$, $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(z_1,z_2) = (r_z\cos{\theta_z}, r_z\sin{\theta_z})$, $(t_1, t_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(t_1,t_2) = (r_t\cos{\theta_t}, r_t\sin{\theta_t})$, $(u_1, u_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(u_1,u_2) = (r_u\cos{\theta_u}, r_u\sin{\theta_u})$ such that:

$$(y_1, y_2) = (x_1,x_2) + (z_1,z_2)$$
$$(t_1, t_2) = (x_1,x_2) + (u_1,u_2)$$

$r_y$, and $r_t$ are known. I know also $\alpha_y = \theta_y + \beta$, $\alpha_t = \theta_t + \beta$, $\theta_z$, $\theta_u$, ${r_z}/{r_u}$. **Values of $\beta$, $r_x$, $r_z$, $r_u$ and $\theta_x$ are unknown** and must be determined. Let's say that I can be satisfied by determining only $\beta$, $\theta_x$ and ${r_x}/{r_z}$ (let's call this relaxed problem $P_3$).

**Is there a solution to $P_2$ or $P_3$?**

I believe there is no solution, because of the difficulty of finding $\beta$ without any "absolute reference" vector like $(z_1, 0)$ in the first $P_1$ problem (where $r_x$ and $\alpha_x$ are known, like if we had $(u_1, u_2) = (0,0)$ in $P_2$), but I could be wrong.

Also, if the answer is negative, would it be possible to determine all unknowns adding another equation $(v_1,v_2)=(x_1,x_2)+(w_1,w_2)$ where the magnitude of $(v_1,v_2)$ is known and its phase also but up to an offset $\beta$, all alike the first two equations?

Comment: It would be easier to read if you write the problem like, given (variables/domains), (equations). I think I understood the problem, but not sure... In the second problem $r_x$ is unkwnown?

Comment: $r_x$ is unknown, as I wrote. The goal of the problem is determining $(x_1,x_2)$ (or equivalently $r_x$ and $\theta_x$) in an expression independent from any other unknown variable. I feel like two equations are not enough for this, but I am unable to formalize it, so I am asking help for this.

Comment: Sorry, reading again I saw that. I asked because this would decouple in two problems like the first, then I would stop thinking about it :)

Comment: When you say "I know also $\alpha_y = \theta_y + \beta$, $\alpha_t = \theta_t + \beta$, $\theta_z$, $\theta_u$, ${r_z}/{r_u}$", it means that $\theta_z$ and $\theta_u$ are given, and that $g_{z,y}=r_z/r_y$ is algo given?

Comment: @Bob, yes exactly.

Comment: What is the role of $\alpha_y$ and $\alpha_t$ in $P_2$?

Comment: $\alpha_y$ and $\alpha_t$ are known (given) values, because they are measured values. Unfortunately $\theta_y$ and $\theta_t$ are known only up to an unknown $\beta$ offset, which must be determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the origin, and let $\vec{OX}=(x_1,x_2),\vec{OY}=(y_1,y_2)$ and $\vec{OT}=(t_1,t_2)$.

Applying the law of cosines to $\triangle{OYT}$, one gets
$$YT=\sqrt{r_y^2+r_t^2-2r_yr_t\cos(\alpha_y-\alpha_t)}$$

Applying the law of cosines to $\triangle{XYT}$, one gets
$$YT^2=r_z^2+r_u^2-2r_zr_u\cos(\theta_z-\theta_u)$$
which can be written as
$$YT^2=\bigg(\bigg(\frac{r_z}{r_u}\bigg)^2+1-2\bigg(\frac{r_z}{r_u}\bigg)\cos(\theta_z-\theta_u)\bigg)r_u^2$$
so one gets
$$r_u=\frac{\sqrt{r_y^2+r_t^2-2r_yr_t\cos(\alpha_y-\alpha_t)}}{\sqrt{\bigg(\dfrac{r_z}{r_u}\bigg)^2+1-2\bigg(\dfrac{r_z}{r_u}\bigg)\cos(\theta_z-\theta_u)}}$$
and
$$r_z=\dfrac{r_z}{r_u}\times r_u=\frac{r_z}{r_u}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{r_y^2+r_t^2-2r_yr_t\cos(\alpha_y-\alpha_t)}}{\sqrt{\bigg(\dfrac{r_z}{r_u}\bigg)^2+1-2\bigg(\dfrac{r_z}{r_u}\bigg)\cos(\theta_z-\theta_u)}}$$

One has
$$r_y\cos\theta_y=r_x\cos\theta_x+r_z\cos\theta_z\tag1$$
$$r_y\sin\theta_y=r_x\sin\theta_x+r_z\sin\theta_z\tag2$$
$$r_t\cos\theta_t=r_x\cos\theta_x+r_u\cos\theta_u\tag3$$
$$r_t\sin\theta_t=r_x\sin\theta_x+r_u\sin\theta_u\tag4$$
It follows from $(1)-(3)$ and $(2)-(4)$ that
$$\cos\theta_y=\frac{K+r_t\cos\theta_t}{r_y},\qquad \sin\theta_y=\frac{L+r_t\sin\theta_t}{r_y}$$
where
$$K=r_z\cos\theta_z-r_u\cos\theta_u,\qquad L=r_z\sin\theta_z-r_u\sin\theta_u$$
Hence, one gets
$$1=\cos^2\theta_y+\sin^2\theta_y=\bigg(\frac{K+r_t\cos\theta_t}{r_y}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{L+r_t\sin\theta_t}{r_y}\bigg)^2$$
which can be written as

$$(K+r_t\cos\theta_t)^2+(L+r_t\sin\theta_t)^2=r_y^2$$
$$K^2+r_t^2+2Kr_t\cos\theta_t+L^2+2Lr_t\sin\theta_t=r_y^2$$
$$2Kr_t\cos\theta_t+2Lr_t\sin\theta_t=r_y^2-K^2-L^2-r_t^2$$
$$\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}\cos(\theta_t-p)=r_y^2-K^2-L^2-r_t^2$$
where
$$\cos p=\frac{2Kr_t}{\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}},\sin p=\frac{2Lr_t}{\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}}$$
So,
$$\theta_t=p+\arccos\bigg(\frac{r_y^2-K^2-L^2-r_t^2}{\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}}\bigg)$$
$$\beta=\alpha_t-\theta_t=\alpha_t-p-\arccos\bigg(\frac{r_y^2-K^2-L^2-r_t^2}{\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}}\bigg)$$
$$\theta_y=\alpha_y-\beta=\alpha_y-\alpha_t+p+\arccos\bigg(\frac{r_y^2-K^2-L^2-r_t^2}{\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}}\bigg)$$

It follows from $(1)(2)$ that
$$r_x=\sqrt{(r_x\cos\theta_x)^2+(r_x\sin\theta_x)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{(r_y\cos\theta_y-r_z\cos\theta_z)^2+(r_y\sin\theta_y-r_z\sin\theta_z)^2}\tag4$$

Finally, $\theta_x$ can be determined by $(1)(2)(4)$.

---

**Added** :

We have already got $r_u$ and $r_z$.

Also, we have already seen that
$$(1)(2)(3)(4)\implies \cos(\theta_t-p)=M\quad \text{where}\quad M=\frac{r_y^2-K^2-L^2-r_t^2}{\sqrt{(2Kr_t)^2+(2Lr_t)^2}}$$
from which one gets
$$\theta_t=p\color{red}{\pm}\arccos(M)$$
where $\arccos (M)$ is such that
$$\cos(\arccos(M))=M\qquad\text{and}\qquad \color{red}{0\leqslant\arccos(M)\leqslant \pi}$$

So, one gets
$$\beta=\alpha_t-\theta_t=\alpha_t-p\mp\arccos(M)$$
and
$$\theta_y=\alpha_y-\beta=\alpha_y-\alpha_t+p\pm\arccos(M)$$

It follows from these that
$$(1)(2)(3)(4)$$
$$\implies (\theta_t,\beta,\theta_y)=(p+\arccos(M),\alpha_t-p-\arccos(M),\alpha_y-\alpha_t+p+\arccos(M)),(p-\arccos(M),\alpha_t-p+\arccos(M),\alpha_y-\alpha_t+p-\arccos(M))$$

For sufficiency, one finally has to check if each of these satisfies $(1)(2)(3)(4)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am reviewing and testing. I fear that I will need to replace the $arccos$ with a two argument $atan2$ to avoid the ambiguity of the $arccos$.

Comment: @BillyJoe : I've just added another explanation.